# Cplex cannot extract expression and index is out of bound

Tags: model, mathematical-optimization, cplex

I wrote code in cplex for these equations, but gave error. I don't know, how to write it. Please help me, if somebody can. I explain my code line to line in code of comments, thanks. I am implementing this article of model:  https://ntnuopen.ntnu.no/ntnu-xmlui/bitstream/handle/11250/2593543/TNSM18.pdf?sequence=1

```
equations:
l ∈ L[output][n0]: Il(f; 0,n0; 
1,n1) = I(v,n1,f,1)
l ∈ L[input][n1]: Il(f; 0,n0; 
1,n1) = I(v,n1,f,1)
n0=sf, ∀n1∈N ,∀f∈F 

l ∈ L[input][n]: Il(f; j,nj ; 
j+1,nj+1) - l ∈ L[output][n]: 
Il(f; j,nj ; j+1,nj+1)=0
∀f∈F, ∀j∈{0,…,Jf}, ∀n∈N, n ≠ 
nj,nj+1,sf,df(or output node)

codes:
int N=11; //total nodes 
number.
range Nunode=1..N;
range tnunode=0..N-1;

int V=5; //total Virtualized 
Network Functions number.
range Nuvnf=1..V;

int J=5; //total service 
function chains number.
range Nusfc=1..J; 
range tnusfc=0..J-1;

int F=20; //total flows 
number.
range Nuflow=1..F;

int L=13; //total links 
number.
range Nulink=1..L;

float Lin[Nunode] = 
[0,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1];
//input of links to each node
float Lout[Nunode] = 
[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,0];
//output of links to each node

dvar boolean I[Nuvnf][Nunode]. 
[Nuflow][Nusfc]; 
//denotes that an Network of 
  Function(NF) instance v 
  hosted at node n is used by 
  the j-th service on the 
  service chain of flow f.
dvar boolean IL[Nulink]. 
[Nuflow][Nusfc][Nunode]. 
[tnusfc][tnunode]; 
//denotes that link l is used 
by flow f to route from the j- 
th to (j+1)-th NF service, 
hosted at node nj and nj+1.

forall (f in Nuflow, j in 
Nusfc: (j+1) in tnusfc, n in 
Nunode: (n+1) in tnunode, v in 
Nuvnf) {         
cons16: sum(l in Nulink: 
Lin[n]==1) IL[l][f][1][0][2]. 
[1] == I[v][1][f][2];
cons17: sum(l in Nulink: 
Lout[n]==1) IL[l][f][1][0][2]. 
[1] 
== I[v][1][f][2];}

forall (f in Nuflow, j in 
Nusfc: (j+1) in tnusfc, n in 
Nunode: (n+1) in tnunode)
cons18: (sum(l in Nulink: 
Lin[n]==1) IL[l][f][j][n]. 
[j+1].[n+1]) – 
(sum(l in Nulink: Lout[n]==1) 
IL[l][f][j][n][j+1][n+1])==0;
```

Answer (score 0):

You have some out of bounds and the following model works:

```
int N=11; //total nodes 
range Nunode=1..N;
range Nunode0=0..N;
range tnunode=0..N-1;

int V=5; //total Virtualized Network Functions number.
range Nuvnf=1..V;

int J=5; //total service function chains number.
range Nusfc=1..J; 
range Nusfc0=0..J;
range tnusfc=0..J-1;

int F=20; //total flows number.
range Nuflow=1..F;

int L=13; //total links number.
range Nulink=1..L;

float Lin[Nunode] = 
[0,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1];
//input of links to each node
float Lout[Nunode] = 
[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,0];
//output of links to each node

dvar boolean I[Nuvnf][Nunode][Nuflow][Nusfc]; 
//denotes that an Network of 
//  Function(NF) instance v 
//  hosted at node n is used by 
//  the j-th service on the 
//  service chain of flow f.
dvar boolean IL[Nulink][Nuflow][Nusfc0][Nunode0][tnusfc][tnunode]; 
//denotes that link l is used  by flow f to route from the j- th to (j+1)-th NF service, 
//hosted at node nj and nj+1.

subject to
{
forall (f in Nuflow, j in 
Nusfc: (j+1) in tnusfc, n in 
Nunode: (n+1) in tnunode, v in 
Nuvnf) {         
cons16: sum(l in Nulink: 
Lin[n]==1) IL[l][f][1][0][2][1] == I[v][1][f][2];
cons17: sum(l in Nulink: 
Lout[n]==1) IL[l][f][1][0][2][1] 
== I[v][1][f][2];}

forall (f in Nuflow, j in 
Nusfc: (j+1) in tnusfc, n in 
Nunode: (n+1) in tnunode)
cons18: sum(l in Nulink: 
Lin[n]==1) IL[l][f][j][n][j+1][n+1]-
sum(l in Nulink: Lout[n]==1) 
IL[l][f][j][n][j+1][n+1]==0;

}
```